# complexity of matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

For $n\times n$ dimensional matrices, it is known that calculating $\operatorname{tr}\{AB\}$ needs $n^2$ scalar multiplications. How many scalar multiplications are needed to calculate $\operatorname{tr}\{ABCD\}$?
Note that $\operatorname{tr}$ means the trace of a matrix.

Comment: What does the tr operation do? Transpose?

Comment: @saadtaame I think it's [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product).

Comment: @saadtaame, trace

Comment: For $s$ $n\times n$ matrices $(A^{(q)})$, you need to sum the $n$ diagonal coefficients $(A^{(1)}\cdots A^{(s)})_{i,i}=\sum_{1\leq i_1,\ldots, i_{s-1}\leq n}A^{(1)}_{ii_1}\cdots A^{(s)}_{i_{s-1}i}$. This yields a total of $n\cdot n^{s-1}\cdot (s-1)$ scalar multiplications and $(n-1)+(n^{s-1}-1)$ scalar sums.

Comment: @julien For 4 matrices this becomes $3n^4$ but Ross's suggestion, below, gives $n^3$. And, where does $(s-1)$ come from?

Comment: @Maesumi I take it that to compute the product (resp sum) of $2$ scalars, you need $1$ multiplication (resp sum). $3$ scalars, $2$ multiplications (resp sums). $s$ scalars, $s-1$ multiplications (resp sums).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, evaluating a trace is order $n^2$-you have $n$ diagonal terms, each of which takes $n$ multiplies and $n$ adds to evaluate.  The final $n$ additions are dominated.  To do trace $ABCD$ I don't see anything better than first finding $AB$ and $CD$, each of which are $n^3$ operations, or, if you are more clever $n^{2.373}$.  Then use your $n^2$ trace calculation, giving order $n^3$ or $n^{2.373}$.    This will work for any number of matrices.  There might be something more clever out there.

Comment: Matrix multiplication can be done in less than $n^3$ multiplication although overhead increases. [Computational Complexity List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)

Comment: @Maesumi:  Thanks for the link.  I had vaguely remembered you could do better.